# Random variable and distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

Given a random variable $\xi$ with $\mathbb E[\xi] = 1$. It is known that $\Pr (\xi > 2T \mid \xi > T) = \Pr (\xi > T); \forall T > 0$. How to find $F(\xi)$?

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Hint: expand using definition of conditional probability. You get $1-F\xi(2T) = (1-F\xi(T))^2$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Don't understand exactly what means $Pr(ξ>2T∣ξ>T)$? It's $\xi$ from T to 2T?

Comment: Is it $P(\xi > 2T | \xi >T)$ in the original question?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst yes, it is

Comment: $\Pr (\xi > 2T \mid \xi > T) = P(\xi> 2T \cap \xi >T)/P(\xi>T) = P(\xi>2T)/P(\xi>T)$

Comment: Hence $\Pr (\xi > 2T) = P(\xi>T)^2$, which gives you the relationship I said above